# Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015, there was a built-in emulator for Android that was Hyper-V compatible (I didn't have to disable Hyper-V to use it), but in Visual Studio 2017 it's no longer there.

Is there a way to add the Hyper-V compatible emulator to Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the "Mobile development with .NET" workload for Visual Studio 2017 it by default selects "Google Android Emulator (API Level 23)" and "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager HAXM" components, and NOT "Visual Studio Emulator for Android". I am unsure of the reasoning for this being the default.

These are optional components for the workload so you can unselect them either from the right summary pane on the Workloads tab or the Individual components tab of the installer.  If you're not using them uninstalling them will save 18GB.  To install the "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" component select it under the "Individual components" tab of the installer.

Since you've already installed just re-launch the Visual Studio Installer in your start menu and hit modify on your existing installation.

**Note:** After I uninstalled the two components I realized it didn't remove the actual AVD's, android images or HAXM so I had to do that via AVD Manager and SDK Manager (SDK Manager I had to relaunch as administrator after the first delete of 3 packages failed).